# class not found exception with Android annotation

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-annotations

I have this code

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_app_list)
public class MainListView extends SherlockFragmentActivity

{

}
```

and this is the exception

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.imona.android/com.imona.android.MainListView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.imona.android.MainListView_"
            android:label="@string/list_navigation"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.VPI" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

is it ok to use Android annotation  with SherlockFragmentActivity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AndroidAnnotation you have to declare the generated classes (ie: with the `_` suffix) in your `AndroidManifest` file.

Here, it seems you're trying to start the original class instead of the generated one. You should use the builder to start your activity. Please have a look to [the wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/HowItWorks#StartingAnAnnotatedActivity) for more information about this.

Answer (score 2):

You should start your activity using the AA generated class instead your class:

```
startActivity(this, com.imona.android.MainListView_.class);
```

or by using the IntentBuilder:

```
com.imona.android.MainListView_.intent(this).start();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems so clear. Look at this line :

```
android:name="com.imona.android.MainListView_"
```

You have declared `MainListView_` , not `MainListView`